# How to derive deceleration parameter in terms of redshift?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

How do I get q in terms of $z$ specifically of this form:

I want to derive the second equation from the first but I'm getting an additional $ \frac{a^2}{H^2}\ $ in the second term

$$ q= -\frac{\ddot{a}}{aH^2}
$$
$$ q= -1+(1+z)\frac{1}{H} \frac{dH}{dz}$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.